# *.blend model animation works in inspector but not in scene

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, blender

https://streamable.com/mho5n

^^ above is a video I took of the problem I am having. As the title states, the animation works just fine in the inspector, but it's not animating at all in the scene. And as you can see, Default Take is firing on a loop as it should. Any help at all would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe Mecanim requires there to be an avatar on the Animator.

Comment: Just tried adding the Avatar that blender built with the *.blend file. Still no effect.